# recv() gets corrupted data

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to receive big data (about 7MB) from my C# server in my C++ application. I use this library to do so: https://github.com/DFHack/clsocket
But when I receive it, I get heavly corrupted data. Here's the code how I get it:

```cpp
unsigned char* image_data = client->ReadBytes(lmi_reply);
```

`lmi_reply` is the exact size of data I want to receive.
`ReadBytes`:

```cpp
uint8* Client::ReadBytes(int r) {
    try {
        uint8* data = new uint8(r);
        this->m_s->Receive(r, data); // m_s is the CActiveSocket object.
        return data;
    }
    catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. When I use both C# client and server, data is exactly same as on server.

Comment: Your buffer has 1 byte length, `new uint8(r)` ? , probably you wanted to allocate array by `new uint8[r]`.

Comment: @rafix07 it's good for small data (like 200 bytes), but not for 7mb

Comment: Is there a difference in encoding scheme ? What do you mean by corrupted data, is it corrupted at the byte level of is it corrupted when you try to convert it to a string ?

Comment: @Sanketh to test the stuff I write retrieved data to the file. On server file size is 3,813,888 bytes. When I receive the file and write it on disk, it's size is 3,813,891 bytes

Comment: @Sanketh also there's no difference in encoding scheme. On both server and client it's ASCII

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use **B** for **bytes** and **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte), one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit), and if you have to refer to a milllibit for some reason that would be 1mb. Thank you.

Comment: I've just checked that the most of my file is 0x00, so not all data did download. But server is surely sends everything in file.

Comment: You're ignoring how many bytes are actually received.  You wouldn't be treating the data as a C-style string and assuming it's nul-terminated, would you?  You also need to [post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *it's good for small data (like 200 bytes), but not for 7mb*  I'm curious - how many **giga**bytes of RAM does your computer have?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing my ReadBytes to this:

```cpp
uint8* Client::ReadBytes(int r) {
    try {
        char* data = new char[r];
        memset(data, 0, r);

        int maxBufferSize = 8192;

        auto bytesReceived = decltype(r){0};
        while (r > 0)
        {
            const auto bytesRequested = (r > maxBufferSize) ? maxBufferSize : r;
            const auto returnValue = recv(this->m_s->GetSocketDescriptor(), data + bytesReceived, bytesRequested, 0);
            if (returnValue == -1 || returnValue == 0)
                return (uint8*)data;

            bytesReceived += returnValue;
            r -= returnValue;
        }

        return (uint8*)data;
    }
    catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't allow the caller to know if a read failure or socket disconnect occurs. Or how many bytes were actually read if less than `r` were read before failure. And if an exception occurs, you leak memory